# Show image upload preview with Lift

Tags: ajax, scala, lift

I want to upload an image with Lift and show it immediatly in some element of the page, without reloading. I want to do it like in [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html) solution (which uses PHP).

The process there is comparatedly simple. I replaced the PHP file with a dummy HTML snippet:

```
<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ajaximage.html">
    <input id="imageFile" name="imageFile" type="file" size="50" maxlength="100000"/>
</form><br/>

<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#imageFile').live('change', function() {
            $("#preview").html('');
            $("#preview").html('<img src="images/processing.jpg" alt="Uploading...."/>');
            $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                target : '#preview'
            }).submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The HTML snippet:

```
<img src="images/someimage.jpg"/>
```

Well, this works. But I need dynamic behaviour obviously. The example page is using instead of my HTML snippet a PHP file, which extracts the data from the request, saves it in the server, and outputs the HTML for the preview image accordingly - `echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."' class='preview'>";`

Now, I have no idea how to accomplish this with Lift.

I found this discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/liftweb/6bxNlbBPJvE But no good solution there besides a vague advice for a framework and HTML5 things which I don't want to use.

---

**Part 2**. I have, already implemented some basics for this in Lift:

HTML:

```
<div class="lift:AddImage.addEntry" form="POST" multipart="true">
        <p><prefix:imageUpload/></p>
        <p><prefix:test/></p>
</div>
```

snippet:

```
package code 
package snippet

import net.liftweb.http.S
import net.liftweb.common.Full
import net.liftweb.common.Empty
import net.liftweb.common.Box
import net.liftweb.http.FileParamHolder
import net.liftweb.util._
import Helpers._
import scala.xml.Group
import scala.xml.NodeSeq
import net.liftweb.http.SHtml
import javax.annotation.Resource
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.io.FileOutputStream

class AddImage {

  // Add a variable to hold the FileParamHolder on submission
  var fileHolder : Box[FileParamHolder] = Empty

  def submitTest () {
    println("submitTest called!")

    val receiptOk = fileHolder match {
      // An empty upload gets reported with a null mime type,
      // so we need to handle this special case
      case Full(FileParamHolder(_, null, _, _)) => true

      case Full(FileParamHolder(_, mime, _, data)) =>

        println("MIME: " + mime)

        if (mime.startsWith("image/")) {

            println("uploading the image: ")

            //scala.io.Source.fromBytes(data)
            try {
                val out: OutputStream = new FileOutputStream("test.jpg");
                out.write(data);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch {
              case e: Exception => println("Exception!: " + e)
            }

          true
        }

      case Full(_) => {
        S.error("Invalid attachment")
        false
      }

      case _ => true
    }

//    (e.validate, receiptOk) match {
//    }
}

  def addEntry(content: NodeSeq): NodeSeq = {

      bind("prefix", content,
              "imageUpload" -> SHtml.fileUpload(f => fileHolder = Box !! f),
              "test" -> SHtml.submit("submitz", submitTest))
  }
}
```

But I'm stuck here because:

- I don't know how to reference the form created by Lift from jquery.
- The javascript submits the form when the upload input field changes, with `ajaxForm()` and inserts the result of the PHP script in the `#preview` element. I don't know how to get the form submit in scala and further output the image HTML, such that it can be inserted in `#preview`

Hope this is not to much questions :) thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer as much as a bunch of pointers that should help you address your questions.

For attaching the JS to your form, I would think you should be able to add an id attribute to the form and attach to it that way. If that is not working for you for some reason, a simple workaround is to wrap the form with a div, like:

```
<div id="wrapper"><form> ... </form></div>
```

And then you can grab that with jquery like: `$('#wrapper form')`. There is a wiki article about ajax file uploads and Lift here: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/AJAX_File_Upload. It also uses a jQuery method for redirecting the form submission, so you might gain some insight there.

With regards to actually displaying the image data, there are a few functions that might come in handy there. The first is [`JsCmds.SetHtml`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M1/net/liftweb/http/js/JsCmds%24%24SetHtml.html) and the other is [`S.fmapFunc`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb/lift-webkit/scaladocs/net/liftweb/http/S%24object.html).

The `JsCmds.SetHtml(id:String, replacement:NodeSeq)` will allow you to replace the contents of an html element that matches a specific id with the provided `NodeSeq`.

The `S.fmapFunc` will allow you to create a function that can return your image. In the example below, you will create a function that reads your image to a byte array and then outputs it to the browser, and that is given a unique id. The second part returns an object that references the unique id and does something with it (in this case an XML Element). So, the example below would return an image tag that calls your image.

```
   S.fmapFunc(() => {
       val mimeType:String = //set mimeType
       val data:Array[Byte] = //get byte array of image
       throw ResponseShortcutException.shortcutResponse(
           InMemoryResponse(data, 
              ("Content-Type" -> mimeType) :: Nil, Nil, 200))
   }) { 
       name => <img src={"?" + name + "=_"} />
   }
```

This is using an [`InMemoryResponse`](http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-9.html#toc-Subsection-9.4.1), which may not be ideal depending on how large your images are. You can use [`StreamingResponse`](http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-9.html#toc-Subsection-9.4.2) as well.

Using the two together, you should be generate Html that contains a link to the image which you can display on the page. There are probably many ways to get this done, so undoubtedly you'll be able to get what you need working. Ajax file uploads can be a bit tricky, so getting everything to work together may take some work, but hopefully this can point you in the right direction.

Also, as a sidenote, the most active place for lift questions is their mailing list: liftweb@googlegroups.com. There are a lot of people that monitor it, including the committers to the project, and they're very responsive.

Comment: @lxx, There is a discussion about Ajax file uploading with some more examples here that may be useful: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/liftweb/OuN1sqRMO_c

Comment: Thanks. Haven't have time to continue this. As soon as I do I'll come back to your answer.